# Azure Backup Server for On prem

Tags: azure

I have on prem infra in which I have around 9 server. I want to use Azure Backup Server not the MARS agent as I want to create a copy on prem. I DON'T HAVE ACTIVE DIRECTORY. the question I have do I need AD on prem and domain join azure backup server. Since I don't have AD can I still use Azure Backup Server????

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done it my self but as I know its not a problem since you will install software on [your server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/backup/backup-azure-microsoft-azure-backup) and vault credentials.

From the link

> 8. The installation happens in phases. In the first phase the Microsoft Azure Recovery Services Agent is installed on the server.
>      The wizard also checks for Internet connectivity. If Internet
>      connectivity is available you can proceed with installation, if not,
>      you need to provide proxy details to connect to the Internet.
>
> The next step is to configure the Microsoft Azure Recovery Services
>   Agent. As a part of the configuration, you will have to provide your
>   vault credentials to register the machine to the recovery services
>   vault. You will also provide a passphrase to encrypt/decrypt the data
>   sent between Azure and your premises. You can automatically generate a
>   passphrase or provide your own minimum 16-character passphrase.
>   Continue with the wizard until the agent has been configured.

Answer (score 0):

You require a Domain Controller in the org and that is the requirement for deploying SC DPM or Azure Backup Server. Both requires DC. Though you can then protect domain joined machine or workgroup machine both

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-support-matrix-mabs-dpm#management-support

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/dpm/prepare-environment-for-dpm?view=sc-dpm-1807#networking